# Page and Post titles not showing in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a slightly odd problem that I have noticed since upgrading Wordpress to 3.7.

In the admin/backend the page and post titles don't show when viewed in lists, for example in the add link dialogue: http://gurumagazine.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/no-page-title-eg1.jpg

The same thing occurs in the menu settings: http://gurumagazine.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/no-page-title-eg2.jpg

I've repaired and optimised the Wordpress database, (no errors) with no difference.
The post and page titles appear normally in the website front end, and in the all page and all post lists of the dashboard.

Any ideas please?

Comment: As @AlexP says it is likely to be a plugin, or perhaps a custom theme, that is pulling page/post titles from a non-standard field, or filtering them before display and the filter is failing. Deactivate all your plugins, and switch back to a generic theme like twenty-thirteen or whatever, and see if the problem disappears. If it goes away, then slowly enable things one-by-one until the problem shows up again, and you'll know the last thing you enabled was at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any plugin? It seems you use some plugin to declare custom post types - test it.
It seems the issue refers plugin

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the pointer. I didn't want to (and can't really) turn off all the plugins and start again (I know this is a fail safe solution). Your clue made me test out landing pages plugin ([here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/landing-pages/)) - which appears to be the culprit. That said, is it possible that two plugins (ie this one and another) are 'interacting' to cause the custom post type issue? Also, how can I (or can I) fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it without looking at it. Still it is better to turn off plugins, test and then turn on. Nake a backup just in case